# How do I checkout the git revision this patch was created for?

Tags: git

I am trying to apply a patch to ffmpeg to fix an [open avfoundation audio capture bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4513). The [patch](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2015-August/177845.html) linked from the issue is reputed to fix the issue, however it is two years old, and does not apply cleanly to the current git code. (The error message is:

```
$ git apply -v  ~/Downloads/avf.patch 
Checking patch libavdevice/avfoundation.m...
error: while searching for:
        CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.1, YES);
    }

    lock_frames(ctx);

    ctx->video_stream_index = stream->index;

    avpriv_set_pts_info(stream, 64, 1, avf_time_base);

    image_buffer      = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(ctx->current_frame);
    image_buffer_size = CVImageBufferGetEncodedSize(image_buffer);

    stream->codec->codec_id   = AV_CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO;

error: patch failed: libavdevice/avfoundation.m:551
error: libavdevice/avfoundation.m: patch does not apply
```

) although that isn't relevant to this question, which is about git.

The patch starts with the lines:

```
 libavdevice/avfoundation.m | 154 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++-------------------
 1 file changed, 91 insertions(+), 63 deletions(-)

diff --git a/libavdevice/avfoundation.m b/libavdevice/avfoundation.m
index 763e675..1ed9cef 100644
--- a/libavdevice/avfoundation.m
+++ b/libavdevice/avfoundation.m
```

and ends with the lines

```
     return 0;
-- 
2.5.0
```

so I am guessing that this patch applies to the 2.5.0 release, with a commit ID starting 763e675

How do I checkout the correct commit so that I can apply the patch? `git log | grep 763e675` doesn't yield any matches. `$ git checkout 763e675` gives the error
`fatal: reference is not a tree: 763e675`.

Comment: $ git checkout 763e675 says fatal: reference is not a tree: 763e675. The full commit ID is presumably the 763e675..1ed9cef but without knowing what the dots represent I'm a bit stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “index” line actually gives the *file*’s hash, not the commit’s.  (The 2.5.0 is just git’s version number.)  You can try doing something like

```
for t in $(git rev-list HEAD libavdevice/avfoundation.m); do
  echo -n "$t: "
  git rev-parse $t:libavdevice/avfoundation.m
done | grep 763e675
```

to find the commit(s) on the current branch (or whatever you put in place of `HEAD`) where that file was in the “before” state of your patch.

Of course, if you would then attempt to bring the changes back to the branch tip (by merge or otherwise), you’ll have to address merge conflicts, in which case it’s just about the same to use `patch --merge` in the first place.

Comment: OK that spits out a commit ID; will try patching

Answer (score 0):

`763e675..1ed9cef` are the hashes of the *blobs* used to generate the patch.

Type `git show 763e675` to check if this specific version of the file exists in your local repository.

---

If you have this specific version of the file, use [Davis Herring's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48438877/86072) to look for the commit which contains this version of the file.

Comment: OK that works but how do I then find the correct commit?